# Python self-programmed game doesnt work at a specific point

Tags: python, list

Hello Stack Overflow Team,
there is a (probably) slight mistake in my code, but i still did not find it yet. Code follows:

```
import random
from random import randint

board = []

print("\n")
board.append(["S", "\a " * 10])

for x in range(2):
    board.append(["\a", "+" * 17, "\a"])

board.append(["\a", "+" * 17, "E"])

for x in range(3):
    board.append(["\a", "+" * 17, "\a"])

board.append(["E", "+" * 17, "\a"])

for x in range(4):
    board.append(["\a", "+" * 17, "\a"])

board.append(["\a", "+" * 17, "E"])

board.append(["\a " * 11])


def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

print("                                  Auf geht's mit 'ner kleinen Runde: Das Brettspiel\n")
print("Deine Figur startet bei \"S\". Jede Runde würfelst du 1- Mal. Die Anzahl der erwürfelten Augen bestimmen die "
      "Schrittweite deiner Figur. Drücke \"Enter\" Taste um zu würfeln.")

print("\n")

token = input("Gib ein Zeichen ein, welches deine Spielfigur werden soll :")

x = 0
y = 0

print_board(board)

randeves = ["Du hast Pech und musst leider 3 Felder zurück", "Du hast Glück und darfst 4 Felder nach vorne", "Deine Position bleibt unverändert"]


while True:
    print("\n")

    wurf = input("Würfle: ")
    dice = randint(1, 6)
    print("Du hast eine " + str(dice) + " gewürfelt\n")

    if x + dice < 13:
        x += dice
        orc = board[x][y]
        board[x][y] = token
        print_board(board)
        board[x][y] = orc

        if orc == "\a":
            print("")
        elif orc == "E":
            print("\n")
            print(randeves[random.randrange(0, len(randeves))])
            if randeves == "Du hast Pech und musst leider 3 Felder zurück":
                x -= 3
            elif randeves == "Du hast Glück und darfst 4 Felder nach vorne":
                x += 4
            elif randeves == "Deine Position bleibt unverändert":
                print("")

    elif x + dice > 13:
        ex = (x + dice) - 13
        y += ex
        x = 13

        orc = board[x][y]
        board[x][y] = token
        print_board(board)
        board[x][y] = orc

        if orc == "\a":
            print("")
        elif orc == "E":
            print("\n")
            print(randeves[random.randrange(0, len(randeves))])
            if randeves == "Du hast Pech und musst leider 3 Felder zurück":
                board[x - 3][y] = token
            elif randeves == "Du hast Glück und darfst 4 Felder nach vorne":
                board[x + 4][y] = token
            elif randeves == "Deine Position bleibt unverändert":
                print("")

    elif x + dice == 13:
        break
```

As you can see, I wanted to program a little board game.
My problem is here that the token in the game does not enter the bottom line but instead I get the error message that the list (which is the board) is out of range. I really don't know how to solve this fault properly.

Comment: Paste the error message

Comment: I doubt the `board` is out of range, most likely one of the indexes being used. If you can't tell from the error message which one it, call `print` with the values involved right be line with the error and run it again. This will give you more information about what is wrong and potentially help you debug your code.

Comment: when you declared `randeves`, its a list, then you check if `randeves == "Du hast Pech... "`, you may want to assign the random to another variable and check it next.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following lines after the creation of the board, it will explain why the y indexes cannot be right :

```
print('length board :', len(board))
for l in board:
    print(len(l), l)

# length board : 14
# 2 ['S', '\x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 ']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', 'E']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['E', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', '\x07']
# 3 ['\x07', '+++++++++++++++++', 'E']
# 1 ['\x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 \x07 ']
```

The way you declare the board, each line is a list that contains 1,2 or 3 elements.

When y = 0, you have no issue, but when you do :

```
y += ex
orc = board[x][y]
```

You cannot fit the list you've created.

I don't have the final answer, you will have to work on the display result, these lines may help you :

```
board.append(["S"]+ ["\a "] * 10)
for x in range(2):
    board.append(["\a"] + ["+"] * 17 + ["\a"])
#[...]
board.append(["\a "]* 11)
```

---

For the `randeves` stuff, you could do it this way :

```
randeves = [("Du hast Pech und musst leider 3 Felder zurück",-3),
            ("Du hast Glück und darfst 4 Felder nach vorne",4),
            ("Deine Position bleibt unverändert",0)]

rand = random.randrange(0, len(randeves))
print(randeves[rand][0])
x += randeves[rand][1]
```

---

I hope there is a German bonus for this one :p